# How to use .fit when the X value is in time format

Tags: python-3.x, svm, svc

Xtrain,Xtest,Ytrain,Ytest = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2, random_state = 10)

Answer (score 1):

You have to preprocess data before feeding your model. Here is a complete working example. First, let's import the required modules:

```
from datetime import datetime

import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, FunctionTransformer
```

Then, define the training data:

```
X = ['17:00','17:05', '17:10', '17:15', '17:20', '17:25']
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 1)
y = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Note, the **X** must be **2D** array. Also, you have to convert time string values to the numerical format. One way to do it is to convert strings to `timestamp` using the builtin `datetime` module. Here is a function which will be used to transform the data:

```
def transform(X, y=None):

    X_new = np.apply_along_axis(
        lambda x: [datetime.strptime(x[0], '%H:%M').timestamp()],
        axis=1,
        arr=X)

    return X_new
```

Don't forget to scale your data since SVC models require data normalization. One can easily combine all the preprocessing steps using the `Pipeline`:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('transformer', FunctionTransformer(transform, validate=False)),
    ('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),
    ('predictor', SVC(kernel='linear'))
])
```

Finally, let's fit the model:

```
print('Build and fit a model...')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
score = pipeline.score(X_test, y_test)

print('Done. Score', score)
```

Comment: ok now i changed the time to float and reshaped it into an array of (154,1) because my y array was of actually 154 rows. code:
x = [17, 17.083333, 17.166667,    17.25, 17.333333, 17.416667]
x =x.values.reshape(6,1)
y = [1,0,1,1,0,1] 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.20)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')  clf.fit(x,y) pred = clf.predict(Xtest) 
score= sk.metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,pred)
report  = sk.metrics.classification_report(y_test, pred, target_names = ['0','1'])
ConfusionMatrix = sk.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test,pred)
error

Comment: error: 
UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for

Comment: Thank you @constt for the previous code. It worked when I run your code. But when I try to see the report and confusion matrix it is giving me error. i am new to this could not find a solution

Comment: When I run the above code again it says: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: The problem is that you've got not enough data to train and validate the model. The F-score error means that some labels weren't predicted so there is no score to calculate for these labels. Try to use more data.

Comment: I have tried with a larger dataset as well. Below is the image of my data